# Hibernate Bidirectional Many to One

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an issue with the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/library.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering tv.mirada.connect.cashless.parking.model.PaymentInterface from tv.mirada.connect.cashless.parking.model.Merchant has the wrong number of column. should be 0
```

I've spent about a day looking for answers and trying thing, with no luck. I don't actually require a bidirectional access, I only need to be able to get a merchant table row from a payment_interface, but it seemed simpler just to include the bidirectional than try to get a unidirectional from the one to the many.

The tables I am using are the merchant table and the payment interface table. I realise that I could have the merchant table directly reference the node table, but the merchant table has an extension of information in the payment interface, so it makes more sense to map it this way.

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Table(name = "park_merchant")
public class Merchant implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="payment_interface_node_id", nullable = false)
    private PaymentInterface paymentInterface;


@Entity
@Table(name = "park_payment_interface", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class PaymentInterface implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "node_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Node node;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "paymentInterface")
    private Set<Merchant> merchants = new HashSet<Merchant>(0);
```

Hopefully, I'm just missing something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, found the solution. I needed to put the @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn in the Merchant table on the getter, rather than on the variable declaration. I'm still not sure why, but at least I know how now.